# prevent Mouse click from closing menus

Tags: vb.net, automation, hook, contextmenu, mouse

I have a project which involves creating a virtual mouse for automation purposes. I want to be able to click with my virtual mouse without affecting the current active window in any way.

I have managed to achieve this by saving the current mouse position and active window before disabling input using block input API.

Then I send the cursor to do the click, bring it back to where it was and set the foreground to the saved window and unblock input.

This works OK however if a context window is open the window is closed when the virtual mouse performs its click.

I have looked at mouse hooks I also tried detecting context menus globally but could not find a way to do this.

If anybody can help with this, please contact me so that I can hopeful learn from your experience.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Paul.

Comment: Have you tried addressing the open windows by name?

Comment: The problem with my issue is detetecting what menus are open. That Is why I would like to just supress to mouse events from all of the other procceses if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a low level hook(not passing the message forward) or in a loop, like this ->

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="PeekMessageA")>
Private Shared Function PeekMsg(
   ByRef msg As WinMsg, ByVal hw As IntPtr, filterMin As UInt16, filterMax As UInt16,
  ByVal remMsg As UInt16) As Boolean

End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure WinMsg
    Dim hnd As UInt32
    Dim msgType As UInt32
    Dim wPmt As UInt32
    Dim lPmt As UInt32 
    Dim time1 As UInt32
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim iPrivate As UInt32
End Structure


'...
Dim msg As WinMsg
 PeekMsg(msg, Nothing, &H200, &H20D, 1) ' 1 on the end indicates that the message should be removed
'...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I will try this and see how I get on.

Comment: No problem. The _msg_ var. holds the info about the mouse click, but I can't tell you what is where since I only explored the keyboard messages. You can find info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mbuttondown)

Comment: I Tried looking into this however the I am trying to automate a QT button click. All of the methods I have tried will work on a normal dialog but fail on a QT dialog. I know that QT does not use windows messages, however some message must be sent back to windows to indicate a click event has taken place. If I intall a mouse hook it can block all events outside of my application.However, the qt buttoun will still click(which I want) but the if i have a context menu open it will still close(Which I dont want.)